# flexbox is not working on digital signature to be sent by email

Tags: html, css, flexbox, digital-signature

[![It is suposed to look like one colum, but when I copy it, and the paste to send, the icons are cluttered. Whats is wrong with the code?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    
     img { display: block; float:left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
    
    
</style>
</head>
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">




 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<table id="Tabla_01" width="267" height="140" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td1>
        <a href="https://hotelawa.cl/"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zXGcJ4sp/ezgif-01.gif" width="242" height="140" alt=""></a></td1>

<div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3">
        <div class="dog"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/AWAPuertoVaras/"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/1X9YVdfm/ezgif-02.gif" width="25" height="41" alt="" style="float: left; display: block; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop;"></a></div>
        <div class="dog"><a href="https://twitter.com/hotelawapvaras?lang=en"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CLhWRRqG/ezgif-04.gif" width="25" height="33" alt="" style="float: left; display: block; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop;"></a></div>
        <div class="dog"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hotel-awa/about/"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4xMM2wFP/ezgif-06.gif" width="25" height="27" alt="" style="float: left; display: block; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop;"></a></div>
        <div class="dog"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/awapuertovaras/?hl=en"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zDSsDCVD/ezgif-08.gif" width="25" height="39" alt="" style="float: left; display: block; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop;"></a></div>
</div>
</tr>

   
</table>




</body>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

What is wrong with this code? I import from bootstrap and looks good, but when I copy that and I want to send it, all the icons are not in the original column

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UydZN.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UydZN.png)

Comment: I can see it run fine in the code snippet box. Can you share screenshot of error?

Comment: The screenshot is already shared. It runs ok, but  then I copy it, and paste to my email, and the fb, ig, linkedin and twitter icons, are not in column otherwise in line

Comment: If you are designing for email, then all styles should be inline. Using only `<table>` is recommended. You may want to format your question for the screenshot link.

Comment: Your `<div>` would break the table layout because it is not inside a `<tr>`. That might be one reason why content is not displayed properly in email.

Comment: Edited like you said. Did I?. Still not working I am not sure about only using <table>. what do you mean?

Comment: Put your `<div>` inside `<td>` otherwise it will break the table layout as I said before. Also `<td1>` is not a valid HTML tag, so fix that typo as well.